# Conjugating symbolic expression

Tags: symbolic, complex, expression-manipulation, assumptions

I am trying to conjugate a symbolic expression, and I have explicitly stated the real terms. However, I simply can't get it to work:

```
Conjugate[
 ComplexExpand[
  I Cos[z] Sin[y] + Sin[z] + 
   A (Cos[z] - I Sin[y] Sin[z]), {z \[Element] Reals, 
   A \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals}]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do the `ComplexExpand` *after* the `Conjugate`

```
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[I Cos[z] Sin[y] + Sin[z] + A (Cos[z] - I Sin[y] Sin[z])]]

(* A Cos[z] + Sin[z] - I (Cos[z] Sin[y] - A Sin[y] Sin[z]) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One straightforward way to take the conjugate of an expression is to replace I with -I

```
ComplexExpand[I Cos[z] Sin[y] + Sin[z] + A (Cos[z] - I Sin[y] Sin[z])] //. I -> (-I)

A Cos[z] + Sin[z] - I (Cos[z] Sin[y] - A Sin[y] Sin[z])
```

As Szabolcs points out in the comments, this solution can be problematic, so beware!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a robust solution.  It's a common but subtle error to try to do this.  Try `1 + I /. I -> -I`.  It gives `1+I`.  The reason is that `I` does not in fact appear in `1+I` anywhere. `1+I` is an atomic object with FullForm `Complex[1,1]`.  Note that the problem is not simply that it doesn't contain `I`, but that it's *atomic*, so `1+I /. 1 -> -1` also has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The simple rule I to -I is not guaranteed to work, e.g.

```
Exp[3 I] /. I -> -I
```

and ComplexConjugate might be too slow (for lengthy expressions). Therefore, I rather define an alternative function to conjugate

```
ClearAll[AltConjugate]
AltConjugate[x_] := ReplaceAll[FullSimplify[x], Complex[a_, b_] -> Complex[a, -b]];
```

This functions looks for the pattern `Complex[a_, b_]` and replaces it by `Complex[a, -b]`.

@celtschk - roots might be problematic, simple functions like `f[x_]=Sqrt[-x^2]` can be handle by simplifying the input function, i.e. adding `FullSimplify` in the definition of `AltConjugate`. Nevertheless, this will fail for functions including more general roots, such as `f[x]=Sqrt[-x^2 +I b]` where both x and b are reals.

Use this carefully and always test it.

Cheers.

Comment: An example where it doesn't work: `Sqrt[-x^2]`. `ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[-x^2]]]` gives `-I Sqrt[x^2], but `ComplexExpand[AltConjugate[Sqrt[-x^2]]]` gives `I Sqrt[x^2]`

Comment: Thanks @celtschk - Square roots are problematic, simplifying the initial expression solves a few simple cases, such the one you just describe. But, it fails for a more general function.